# How to add an action to share button in navigation bar with Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, selector, uinavigationitem

I am trying to add an action to my share button in navigation bar but I don't know how and where to define my "shareAction" method. To add share button, I have the following code in viewWillAppear :

```
UIBarButtonItem *shareButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
                                target:self
                                action:@selector(shareAction:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = shareButton;
```

Comment: Action is just a private method.you can define inside your current class.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

in your implementation.m file

```
- (void) viewWillAppear 
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UIBarButtonItem *shareButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
                                    target:self
                                    action:@selector(shareAction:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = shareButton;
}

-(void)shareAction:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"share action");
}
```

Comment: please elaborate on your answer, maybe explain what the code is doing and how it solves the problem. This will help others who see your code in the future

Answer (score 7):

Swift

```
    let shareBar: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem:.Action, target: self, action: Selector("userDidTapShare"))

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = shareBar

     func userDidTapShare() {
          //Implementation goes here ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3.0

Write this code in `viewDidLoad`

```
 let btnShare = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:.action, target: self, action: #selector(btnShare_clicked))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnShare
```

Share button action

```
func btnShare_clicked() {
        print("Share button clicked")
    }
```